# How can be reverse port forwarding connection established without encryption?

Tags: ssh, networking, docker, port-forwarding, socat

I have a docker image running on localhost and what I want is to let the docker container communicate with my host's application on a specific port.

I cannot change the `network=bridge` docker configuration to anything else.

What I'm using right now:

```
screen ssh docker-container -R 16000:localhost:16000
[Ctrl] + A -> D
```

This means that there is an encryption layer, which is not needed at all and it adds latency to the communication, which is what I want to get rid of.

**Can I establish a reverse port forwarding tunnel between two hosts without encryption?**

I have a feeling like `socat` could be the solution.

Comment: Are you sure the latency from the encryption is measurable in any way?

Comment: without encryption is just `rsh`

Comment: @guiverc I think `rsh` doesn't support port forwarding at all, or am I wrong?

Comment: @ilkkachu It would be measurable/comparable in a case when there would be a solution to my question :D